# how can I run a powershell script after successful publish to local folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to run a powershell script after I have published a project to a local folder. Is it possible to run a script after a publish has been made?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post-build event to run a PowerShell script after a successful build and publish of your project.

[image]